# Алгоритм действий при работе с файлами и анализе данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, алгоритм, файлы

У меня есть 2 файла json с информацией хранящейся в формате JSON. Пример

```
[{"points": "87", 
"title": "SantaFe", 
"description": "Fast car.",
"taster_name": "Calvin Klein", 
"price": 500, 
"designation": "Santo Ricko ",
"color": "White",
"region_1": "Etna", 
"region_2": null, 
"province": "Silicon Valley", 
"country": "Germany",
"plant": "Helicopter st."}, 
...,
{...}]
```

В этих файлах есть одинаковые данные, мне нужно объединить эти файлы, но чтоб без повторений..
+надо отсортировать эти данные по цене, а если чена одинаковая, то по названию. Затем надо проанализировать данные и вывести *страну в которой больше всего машин*, *самую популярную машину в конкретной стране*... **нельзя использовать никакие библиотеки**, все надо делать на *чистом питоне*. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно соединить два файла и как мне в принципе анализировать данные из выходного файла?

Comment: Сами файлы никак не нужно соединять. Просто читаете данные сначала из одного файла, потом из другого, потом из третьего и т.д. Добавляете все в один список. Потом уже обрабатываете как вам нужно. Т.е. `open`, `json.read`, складываете прочитанные списки, потом `sort` по нужным параметрам.